# Calling HTML files using Button Click and not getting Data

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using [this](https://github.com/DavidIsrawi/Roraima) sample code to create List and Detail page functionality.

In this sample code, We are using bottom tabs and getting data like this:

[image]

But, I want to use simple HTML buttons instead of Bottom tabs in my project to call respective HTML files, like this:

```
<button type = "submit" onClick= "window.location= 'templates/list.html'">Artists</button>
```

And as a result, I am getting view like this (no data, no list, no design, no style) whereas I was expecting like above one only without bottom tabs.

[image]

Comment: Well, what do you think `window.location` does? It replaced the entire page

Comment: @JuanMendes no issues with that, my concern is why I am not getting data, list and design, If I directly call list.html.... see second screenshot and compare with first one... so you'll find the difference.... what exactly I am looking for

Comment: It's probably because the html page is being fetched with AJAX and inserted into the existing DOM. You'll notice that you don't have your header and footer anymore.

Comment: @Sophie — "see second screenshot and compare with first one... so you'll find the difference" — They have completely different URLs.

Comment: angular is not loaded in that template ! we need your code on how you are calling things

Comment: @Angular_10 hey hi... here is the code which I am using : https://github.com/DavidIsrawi/Roraima

Comment: I think you can't use that way in ionic especially when you are using  </ion-tab> and <ion-nav-view> you gotta stick to that design in orginal source code

Comment: @Angular_10 ok no issues, please check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479905/ionic-list-item-click-show-detail-in-another-html-page ... I have done almost 80% work of mine, now only 20 % is left