# Ionic List Item Click show Detail in another HTML Page

Tags: html, angularjs, list, ionic-framework

I have created a list of Items using the following code:

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title> Creators </title>
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
            .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.items = [
                    { 
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "Steve Jobs"
                    },
                    { 
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "Bill Gates"
                    }    
                ];
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
            <h1 class="title">Smart List</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I am getting:

[image]

But now I would like to `open another html` page where I can show `detail` of **tapped list item**, like : **Id and Name** in case of above example

Comment: I'm not sure how easy is for you to open a new html and route back again to list but yea u can do it by adding one more route in your stateprovider and do as similar to your tabs.But I would suggest best way of doing this is show a pop over or modal.can you give me a plunker of your code?

Comment: @Angular_10 thanks for commenting and suggestion... could you please show me the way of doing this with the use of stateprovider only... share changes as you think I should write... actually its bit urgent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N7njvKwSAHfh3pAnlZpv) with some corrected changes ! Cheers to @Nimsesh Patel for creating this.

New html

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
      <button ng-click="closeModal()">close</button>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <h3>{{items[currentItem].id}}</h3>
      <p>{{items[currentItem].name}}</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

In your controller

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
            .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
                $scope.currentItem = 1;
                $scope.items = [
                    { 
                        "id": "1",
                        "name": "Steve Jobs"
                    },
                    { 
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "Bill Gates"
                    }    
                ];
                $scope.getdetails = function(id){
                  $scope.currentItem = id;
                  $scope.modal.show();

                };
                $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('detail.html', {
                  scope: $scope,
                  animation: 'slide-in-up'
                }).then(function(modal) {
                  $scope.modal = modal;
                });
                $scope.closeModal = function() {
                  $scope.modal.hide();
                };
            });
```

In main html where ng-repeat is there

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Smart List</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" item="item" ng-click="getdetails($index)">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using stateProvider. Here is the example of chats list and chat detail In which when you click on particular chat, chat details will be shown in chat details page.
Here is app.js file which includes two controllers.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller('ChatDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, ChatService) {
$scope.chatId = $stateParams.chatId;
 $scope.chat = ChatService.getChat($scope.chatId);
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, ChatService) {
 $scope.chats = ChatService.getChats();
})
.service('ChatService', function() {
 return {
   chats: [
     {
       id: "1",
       message: "Chat Message 1"
     },
     {
       id: "2",
       message: "Chat Message 2"
     },
   ],
   getChats: function() {
     return this.chats;
   },
   getChat: function(chatId) {
     for(i=0;i<this.chats.length;i++){
       if(this.chats[i].id == chatId){
         return this.chats[i];
       }
     }
   }
 }
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
   .state('chats', {
     url: "/chats",
     templateUrl: "templates/chats.html",
     controller: "ChatsCtrl"
   })
   .state('chatDetails', {
     url: "/chats/:chatId",
     templateUrl: "templates/chatDetails.html",
     controller: "ChatDetailsCtrl"
   });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/chats");
})
```

Here is Html page's body code.

```
    <body>
        <ion-pane class="pane">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="templates/chats.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Chats">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="chat in chats" href="#/chats/{{chat.id}}">
   Chat {{ chat.id }}
 </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="templates/chatDetails.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Chat Details">
<ion-content>
   <ion-item><b>Chat:</b> {{ chat.id }}</ion-item>
   <ion-item><b>Message:</b> {{ chat.message }}</ion-item>
 </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
```

Comment: I have already seen kind of functionality here: https://github.com/DavidIsrawi/Roraima ......... But believe me I do not want to make things complicate unnecessarily... I am looking for clean approach to do this...

Comment: This is somewhat cleaner example. https://plnkr.co/edit/N7njvKwSAHfh3pAnlZpv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function on click of item like following

```
<ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="functionName()">
           {{ item.name }}
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.functionName = function(){
   // open new html modal to show new screen using following
   $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/views/details.html',{
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'none',
            backdropClickToClose: false
        }).then(function(modal){
            $scope.modal= modal;
            $scope.modal.show();
        });
}
```

Using this you can show details of clicked item on new screen.

Comment: @Sophie this answer should help you and it depicts what I said !

Comment: can you create a plunker to demo that would be nice and helpful

Comment: @Angular_10 yes I have tried "Mr.Helper" way but did not get any success, here is my updated code... please make change as you think I should need to use to get it done: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6HxxqmbPu1BS1d3NHlkSElXZ2c

Comment: can you create a sample plunker by any means as at this moment I cant download your files

Comment: sample plunker ? @Angular_10 whenever you will be able to download, please download and try ... I am very new to Ionic framework and I really want to get it done.... ASAP... please guide me further

Comment: Please check above screenshot... this is what I have achieved !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127616/discussion-between-angular-10-and-sophie).